# how to put unicode characters in string-array as external resource

Tags: android, arrays

I am using unicode characters in my android application. As I want them to be external resources, I created string-array in strings.xml as follows

```
<string-array name="geez_first_chars">
    <item >"\u1200"</item>
    <item >"\u1208"</item>
    <item >"\u1210"</item>
    <item >"\u1218"</item>
    ....
</string-array>
```

I accessed them then in my Java code as follows:

```
String fidels[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.geez_first_chars);
```

But, there is runtime error, please help me fix this.

Comment: post the logcat output of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the above problem myself. The runtime error was caused by the calls getResources()...
Putting the "String fidels[]" behind I moved the calls to onCreate() and it just run fine.

Cheers!